# How to return Javascript variable to wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, variables

I use this Javascript code to create a dialog box to ask some thing to user and after decide what to do depending of the response.

```
function dialogToCont()
{
    var retVal = confirm("Do you want to continue ?");
    if( retVal == true )
    {
        alert("User wants to continue!");
        return true;
    }else
    {
        alert("User does not want to continue!");
        return false;
    }
}
```

and in my plugin I want to call this to show the dialog box to the user.

In my php code I want to do something if the response of the use is true or false like this :

```
$tmp = "<script type='text/javascript'>dialogToCont();</script>";
//it is not correct this..
if ( tmp )
{...
 // do something...
}
```

I have already registered my javascript code with wp_enqueue_script method.

Comment: Maybe the way I thinking is totally incorrect. Have I to use something like a hidden input field to save pass the variable through this?

Comment: The question I marked as a duplicate is about jQuery specifically, not Javascript in general, but the answer is the same.

Comment: In some point your suggestion is correct. This that I tried to do it was not correct by this way because ajax work in client side and this part of code was "running" into the server side.
Finally I re-design my plan. I will put some meta data to the admin panel like check box to let the user decide instead dialog box.